# How to select rows in MySQL/PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to display my first 10 users and their information by uid. When I use the code below, it only returns a single uid:

```
include "db_conx.php";
$sql = ('SELECT uid,username,country FROM users ORDER BY uid DESC LIMIT 10');
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
echo $result->fetch_object()->uid;
```

What function am I supposed to use to display rows correctly?

Comment: You should probably loop through the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
include "db_conx.php";
$sql = ('SELECT uid,username,country FROM users ORDER BY uid DESC LIMIT 10');
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while($var = $result->fetch_object()->uid){
echo $var;
}
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you  get a list of object you should use a loop for show them

```
include "db_conx.php";
$sql = ('SELECT uid,username,country FROM users ORDER BY uid DESC LIMIT 10');
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {             
   $row->uid;
}
```